# Combining regroup with get_foo_display in Django templates

Tags: django, templates

I'm using the [regroup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) template tag to group queryset output on a Choices field. In the model:

```
  RESOURCE_TYPES = (
      ('tut','External tutorial'),
      ('read','Additional reading'),
      ('org','Company or organization'),                         
  )

restype = models.CharField('Resource type',max_length=6,choices=RESOURCE_TYPES)
```

in the view:

```
resources = Resource.objects.filter(tutorial=tutorial)
```

in the template:

```
{% regroup resources by restype as resource_list %}
{% for type in resource_list %}
<h3>{{type.grouper}}</h3>
```

So type.grouper renders as 'tut' or 'org' on the page, rather than the long form. Normally you would use the [get_foo_display](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/choices/) syntax to get at the value of the choice, rather than the key. But the value doesn't seem to be available after going through regroup. There's no way I can find to use get_foo_display on {{type.grouper}}.

It makes sense when you think about it, but what's the workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What happens if you do

```
{% regroup resources by get_restype_display as resource_list %}
```

Comment: It works! That's fantastic Daniel. I'll file a documentation patch for this.

Comment: Simple, elegant, and exactly what I was looking for. One upvote doesn't seem sufficient.